# the result dual store - load atomic operation

Tags: c++, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

At start `a` and `b` are `0`

- In thread 1,atomic write `a=1` then atomic read `b`
- In thread 2,atomic write `b=1` then atomic read `a`

If I want to make sure thread 1 can read `b=1` or thread 2 can read `a=1`,which memory order should I use,and why?

Comment: To me it sounds like you don't need atomics at all, just use message passing instead of shares variables.

Comment: You need `memory_order_seq_cst` (the default) to prevent the case where they both read 0.  This is the classic StoreLoad reordering litmus test.  https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/.  Looking for a duplicate...  (Unless you mean that you want to also rule out them both loading 1?  You can't rule that out with any memory ordering, since it's possible with a simple interleaving of source orders.)